# Can I upgrade DataStax Enterprise directly from 4.5.1 to 4.8.9 ?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Do we have to upgrade to interim version DSE 4.6 then go for 4.8 ?
we are using DSE 4.5.1 for our Cassandra db only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to upgrade to 4.8.x from 4.5.y.

Cassandra major release (e.g. 2.1 to 3.0) or major point release (e.g. 2.0 to 2.1), might involve sstable version change which will require running upgradeSSTables from nodetool. Cassandra sstable versions are normally backward compatible with previous version but not before that. That’s why if you want to say upgrade to 2.2 from 2.0 then you would first upgrade to 2.1. While you are doing a rolling upgrade to 2.1 from 2.0 your cluster will be in mixed mode (some nodes still on 2.0 while other upgraded to 2.1). This will be OK because Cassandra will support reading from previous sstable version. But before you can upgrade to 2.2 you need to upgrade sstables. Once that is done (nodetool upgradesstables) on all the nodes then you can upgrade to 2.2.

In above example I have talked about Apache Cassandra version, but similar logic can be applied to DSE. Here is a link of which Cassandra version is used by various DSE and other upgrade related info
[upgradedDSE47or48](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgdDSE47or48.html)
The usual restrictions and limitation apply while cluster is in mixed mode as mentioned [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/cassandra/upgrdCassLimit.html)